# Checking how many elements of a tree satisfy a predicate

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I want to count how many elements in a Tree "respect" a certain rule.

For example:

For the data type:

```
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node Tree Int Tree
```

and the function signature:

```
nSatisfy :: (Int->Bool) -> Tree -> Int
```

for the input:

```
(>0) Tree
```

it should return the values of the tree that are (>0).

Here's what i've tried:

```
nSatisfy :: (Int->Bool) -> Tree -> Int
nSatisfy condition Leaf x = if condition x then 1 else 0
nSatisfy condition (Node left x right)
    |(if condition x then 1 else 0) + nSatisfy condition Tree
    | otherwise = nSatisfy condition left || nSatisfy condition right
```

Any help?

UPDATE:

I found a much simpler way to do this:

```
nSatisfy :: (Int->Bool) -> Tree -> Int
nSatisfy n (Leaf x) = if n x then 1 else 0
nSatisfy n (Node left x right) = (if n x then 1 else 0) + (nSatisfy n left) + (nSatisfy n right)
```

Comment: Your guard syntax is messed up, it should be `| <boolean expression> = <int expression>` on each line.  It also looks like you're over thinking things a bit.  If you have `left` and `right` as sub-trees, you just want to call `nSatisfy condition` on each of those then add them together.  You could (and should) do this without the guard.

Comment: `nSatisfy condition Leaf x` should be `nSatisfy condition (Leaf x)`

Answer (score 3):

That function is doing way too much at once: count, check a predicate and traverse a complex type.

I suggest to write a function

```
listFromTree :: Tree -> [Int]
```

and build your `nSatisfy` with `listFromTree` and the Prelude functions `length` and `filter`.

---

Edit: OP found a working answer himself, now here my code:

```
nSatisfy' p = length . filter p . listFromTree

listFromTree :: Tree -> [Int]
listFromTree (Leaf x) = [x]
listFromTree (Node left x right) = listFromTree left ++ [x] ++ listFromTree right
```

Functions that check something, i.e. `a -> Bool` are usually called [predicate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)) and shortened with `p` like in [filter](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter). `n` is usually an integer, not a function.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing *wrong* with your updated version. Luis Casillas and Franky, however, are encouraging you to think about breaking up the ideas in your code into the smallest possible pieces. This is generally the best way to deal with programming problems, for several reasons:

1. The human brain can only think about so much at once. If you break up the problem into different pieces or layers and only think about one at a time, you have a much better chance of solving it correctly.
2. You will create functions that you can reuse to solve other problems, and *ways of thinking* that you can reuse to solve other problems.
3. You will be able to test each piece of the solution separately. In this case, the problem is simple enough to test the whole solution, but in most realistic cases, waiting until you have a complete solution before you start testing will lead you down the rabbit hole of "I know it's wrong, but I don't know where".
4. Once you've broken your problem down into little pieces, you are much more likely to find that *other people have already solved those problems*. Sometime soon, your Haskell study will lead you to polymorphic data structures and functions. By generalizing your `Tree` type a little, you will gain the ability to use library functions like `toList`, `fmap`, and `sum`, building your solution from solution pieces that other people have written for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's a hint. You can solve this problem much more easily if you split it into three parts:

1. A `mapTree :: (Int -> Int) -> Tree -> Tree` function that applies the supplied function to every `Int` in the tree.
2. A function that tests an individual `Int` and returns `1` if it satisfies your condition, `0` otherwise.
3. A `sumTree :: Tree -> Int` function that sums all the `Int`s in a tree.

Then you can put these three parts together to solve your problem fairly easily.  And what's more, `mapTree` and `sumTree` will be useful for other problems.

Comment: why is this wrong ?                                                                                 `mapTree :: Int -> Tree -> Tree
mapTree n Leaf x = Leaf (n x)
mapTree n (Node left x right) = Node ((mapTree n left) n x (mapTree n right))`